# Detect ongoing speech from AVSpeech and AVUtterance in Swift

Tags: ios, avspeechutterance

I gather you can use a delegate method to tell when AV speech has finished

```
 extension MyViewController: AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate {

    func speechSynthesizer(synthesizer: AVSpeechSynthesizer, didFinishSpeechUtterance utterance: AVSpeechUtterance) {
            print("speech finished")
        }

    }
```

But how can you tell if speech is ongoing and has *not* yet finished?

Right now, I start some speech with

```
voice.speak(utt)
//do something
```

I would like to do something while the person is speaking `before` they finish.  Merely putting a line do something below the `voice.speak(utt)` doesn't seem to work.  I think this is due to a race condition. I can't be sure it fires as soon as the voice is triggered and before the delegate method fires after the utterance is complete.

A completion bloc  won't help because I want to do something before the utterance is completed.  So how can I do something while the utterance is taking place, in other words start doing something at the precise moment the utterance starts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can you tell if speech is ongoing...

Retrieve the boolean value that indicates whether the synthesizer is speaking from the `isSpeaking` method of your AVSpeechSynthesizer instance.

> ...and has not yet finished?

Detect the beginning thanks to the `didStart` method of the [`AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate` protocol](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#speech-synthesis) that will provide the concerned utterance.

Besides, if you want to know exactly the location of the vocalization, use the `willSpeakRangeOfSpeechString` of the `AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate` protocol.

[All these elements](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios-wwdc-18236.html#wwdc-2018-making-ios-talk-with-avspeechsynthesizer) should help you to **detect ongoing speech from AVSpeech and AVUtterance** as desired.